# How can I hang a heavy frame without making holes in the walls?

Tags: walls, hanging

I live in an apartment, so I don't want to put holes in the wall, but I have a large (2'x3') wire-suspended frame, weighing 14 pounds, that I'd like to hang. The heaviest-duty 3M Command product (the [Sticky Nail Wire-Back Hanger](http://www.command.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/NACommand/Command/Products/Catalog/~/Command-Sticky-Nail-Wire-Back-Hanger?N=5924736%203294774820%203294857497&loc=en_US&plmlblid=1319218325558&rt=rud)) only holds 8 pounds and 18"-24" frames. The Command FAQ says they “don't recommend” using multiple hooks to hang heavier things. Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, it's not that big of a chore to patch nail holes. I'd go with nails, then just patch/paint (if you have the paint) when you move out.

Answer (score 8):

This may be thinking outside the box, but there are other ways to display a picture rather than "hanging" them. Hopefully these inspire some solutions...

[image]

Have you considered using some sort of display easel [like the one above](http://www.pleinairco.com/servlet/the-769/elmwood-display-easel-artist/Detail?gclid=CI6Dkpa_r7YCFQzqnAoddlQAsg) instead?

[Google Search: Photo Display Easel](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_rn=8&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=_91EFYl1hxKIf5F3Aw33JA&cp=17&gs_id=6c&xhr=t&q=photo+display+easel)

Compression poles are also an interesting way to hang things without causing damage:

[image]

Or if you are more industrious, you can construct some sort of free standing (or leaning) panel to hang the picture from. A nicely framed section of painted drywall or other type of surface can make a nice accessory for the room. It can be made free standing or designed to lean up against the wall without causing any permanent damage.

Comment: Good points, was thinking the 3M command option could be combined with your idea for a hybrid solution: make a 'H' frame below the picture, held to wall with 3M, then the 8lb 3M picture stickers would only have to keep the picture from tipping off the 'H' frame. Look ma, no holes!

Answer (score 5):

The reason they don't recommend using multiple fixings if that if one fixing fails then the others are likely to fail due to the extra load on them.

For a heavy item you will need to fix it to something, whether it is in the wall or ceiling, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So either I take a greater risk of the thing falling or I need to negotiate with the property manager :-\ Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Buildex EZ solver](http://fastening-solutions.itwbuildex.com/item/hollow-wall-anchors/e-z-products-hollow-wall-and-wallboard-anchors/5052907?) is a great problem solver.. [image]

- supports 50lbs
- will install into a stud (if you happen to hit one)
- Installs with a #2 phillips screwdriver or drillgun , which you then use to install the screw
- Does not go very deep into wall, lessening danger of hitting wire or pipe (Still is a possibility)

Repairing the hole is easy (reverses out to deinstall) using patching plaster or spackle (spaekle)

Disclaimer:  Not affiliated with Buildex

Comment: This breaks the "no holes" rule.

Comment: "Don't want to" isn't as strong as "I may not".  Safety trumps inconvience in having to do a plaster repair.

Comment: I'd rather plan on some trivial effort to fill nail holes when I move than deal with unplanned effort and cost when a framed mirror (for example) drops and gouges a hardwood floor or cracks a tile.